# Peter's Denial and the Rooster Crowing

Tags: matthew, mark

In Matthew 26:34, we see Jesus telling Peter that before rooster crows, you will disown me three times:

“Truly I tell you,” Jesus answered, “this very night, before the rooster crows, you will disown me three times.” [NIV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2026:34&version=NIV)

However, in Mark, it says the rooster will crow twice:

“Truly I tell you,” Jesus answered, “today—yes, tonight—before the rooster crows twice you yourself will disown me three times.” [NIV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%2014:30&version=NIV)

Is this a discrepancy, or is the language used in Matthew allow for plurality?  What is the significance of the rooster crowing twice?

Comment: A belated welcome to BH.SE.  Did you get the sort of answer you were looking for?  There are lots of examples of Matthew "correcting" or "simplifying" Mark.  In this case, the way Mark presents Jesus' words is a bit convoluted and Matthew gets right to the point: "you will disown me three times and then the rooster will crow."  Was there something more you were asking about?

Comment: @Brian Mains The Roman custom of night watches with the blowing of a trumpet at intervals would be heard at Jerusalem. The cock-crow was the third watch (Mark 13:35!). Each watch had a different tune, and multiple blasts, thus the reference to multiple cock-crow soundings.

Answer (score 4):

One issue is that Mark was written in Rome about 30 years after the actual events.  According to the earliest tradition of Papias, Origen, and Tertullian, the source of the account was actually the Apostle Peter.

While some commentators maintain that the “twice” refers to specific points of time—midnight and dawn, respectively—A Dictionary of Christ and the Gospels, edited by James Hastings, indicates that

> “as a matter of fact cocks crow during the night, in the East as
>   elsewhere, at irregular times from midnight onward.”

Apparently, Jesus was not referring to the specific time when Peter would deny him. Rather, he was giving a sign to mark his words to Peter, which were accurately fulfilled that very night.  I find it interesting and noteworthy that this is exactly the kind of detail that Peter would have remembered of the account and thus would have passed this onto Mark to record in his writing.

Comment: The early Church Fathers held that Mark's Gospel account was more or less dictated to him by Peter.

Answer (score 3):

This sort of detail is something that scholars use to support the concept of Markan priority. The line of thinking is that Mark generally includes more granular details than the other accounts (as the one you mentioned above). The next step is that this would imply that Mark was temporally "closer" to the original event and so was able to recall/include these events (perhaps from Peter).

Answer (score 2):

The rooster could not have been the actual bird.  First, this was the night prior to the Passover.  There would not have been any foul inside the city gates in preparation of this event.  Secondly, the term "rooster crowing" was a common term relating to the third watch as recorded in Mark 13:35.  The third watch 'rooster' is the guard tower calling out the end of the watch.

Comment: [We're a little different from other sites](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423).

Answer (score 1):

It might be interesting to know that from Mark's text in some of the oldest codices, this mention of a cock crowing twice seems to be missing.
In Codex Bezae, Codex Sinaiticus, and Codex Ephraemi Syri Rescriptus the cock just crows.

[Greek New Testament Mark 14:30](https://greeknewtestament.net/mk14-30)

To complicate the matter further when we check how it plays out in the fulfillment of this prediction in Mark 14:66-72 we see that the old codices are not very consistent. Only the Codex Sinaiticus is completely consistent in reporting on all counts that the cock crows only one time and only after Peter has denied Jesus three times. Codex Vaticanus does not report a cock crowing the first time in 14:68 just like Sinaiticus, but most others do. And all except Sinaiticus report in 14:72, the cock crowing εκ δευτερου which is commonly translated as for the second time. It is possible the expression εκ δευτερου is the ultimate cause of all this confusion. Another correct translation of this expression could be read in this instance as **following** or **after** (the third denial) the cock crowed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an interesting story...Many fowl are not unclean animals and would have been within the city. It would have been impossible to remove all animals considered unclean. Roosters are known to crow at such hours as 3:00 AM which was perfect timing. Going back to original languages one finds the same wording. Sound a lot like the stories that circulate about the eye of the Needle being a small gate....Not true according to the original languages....

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/47955)

Answer (score 0):

I will have to go back into my reserve library, but my research revealed that, just as there were night-time town criers in olden England and colonial America, so also the Romans had the night divided into "watches" designated by trumpet blowings.

The last division was called the **Cock crowing**. I once heard a trumpeter give this blast in a lecture.  So Peter would not have missed this signal predicted by Jesus. It was heard throughout Jerusalem.  (How would you like your sin to be proclaimed to all the people! At least in the mind of Peter it would have seemed like it.)

As far as the number of blasts, Martin Klatt's answer is enlightening, and I would defer to that.  However it does not rule out the possibility that each division blast had a designated number of "toots". (Just as a chime clock rings multiple times at each hour.)

To explain this event we need only go to the Gospel of Mark, 13:35:  *Watch ye therefore for ye know not when the master of the house cometh: at even, or at midnight, or at the cock-crowing, or in the morning.*  It was the third watch when Peter was to have betrayed Jesus.

HISTORY The ancient Jews had three night watches: (1) Beginning of the watches-Lam 2:14 (sunset to 10 am), (2) Middle watch-Jud. 7:19 (10 am to 2 pm), (3) Morning watch-Exod. 14:24 (2 am to sunrise).

When the Romans conquered Judea, they implemented the Roman watches which were 4 in number (See the above scripture, Mark 13:35)  The **cock-crowing** that Jesus referred to, was the 3rd watch of the night.